# Get the error "Unknown CMake command perlasm" in boringssl

Tags: android, boringssl

I'm trying to use [boringssl](https://github.com/google/boringssl) in Android environment.

I added the code I needed,

- `include/openssl`
- `ssl`
- `crypto`
- `third_party/fiat`
  to my project.

Now, `CMakeLists.txt` of the added project has been added and applied to `build.gradle`.

```
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            // Provides a relative path to your CMake build script.
            path "src/main/openssl/ssl/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
        cmake {
            // Provides a relative path to your CMake build script.
            path "src/main/openssl/crypto/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
        cmake {
            // Provides a relative path to your CMake build script.
            path "src/main/openssl/crypto/fipsmodule/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
```

I also added it to `MainActivity.java`.

```
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("ssl");
        System.loadLibrary("crypto");
    }
```

When I run the code for testing I get an error:

```
/app/src/main/openssl/crypto/fipsmodule/CMakeLists.txt:1 (perlasm):
Unknown CMake command "perlasm".
```

Please tell me how to fix this error. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Basically the CMake cant recognized the "perlasm"

To fix this error, you will need to modify the CMakeLists.txt file in the src/main/openssl/crypto/fipsmodule directory to remove or replace any occurrences of the "perlasm" command. Since BoringSSL does not use assembly language for its cryptographic routines like OpenSSL does, you should not need to use the "perlasm" command in your CMake build script.

src/main/openssl/crypto/fipsmodule/CMakeLists.txt

Remove or comment out any lines that use the "perlasm" command
Example:
perlasm(${ARCH_DIR}/sha512-x86_64.pl sha512-x86_64_asm.S ${ARCH})

Add the source files to the library
add_library(fipsmodule
sha512-x86_64_asm.S
other_source_files.cpp
)

Set include directories, etc.
target_include_directories(fipsmodule PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../..)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have made corrections as you said. Afterwards, the error `The dependency target "boringssl_prefix_symbols" of target "crypto" does` occurs. Is there a way to set `boringssl_prefix_symbols`?